# Discord Bot fails to reconnect to voice chat after leaving

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, voice

im running a discord bot on heroku (just messing around with discord.py simply)and i was following a yt tutorial about "how to play yt from discord.py" it uses discordutils module for it .
the problem is when i play a song after turning bot on its fine and good but after i disconnect the bot from the server i can't play another song with my bot following error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_playing'
```

also the play function is:

```py
@commands.command()
    async def play(self ,ctx, *, url):
        player = music.get_player(guild_id=ctx.guild.id)
        if not player:
            await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
            player = music.create_player(ctx, ffmpeg_error_betterfix=True)
        if not ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
            await player.queue(url, search=True)
            song = await player.play()
            await ctx.send(f"Playing {song.name}")
        else:
            song = await player.queue(url, search=True)
            await ctx.send(f"Queued {song.name}")
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware (from my own bot experience, at least) one of the usual causes for this is that the context is lost when the bot disconnects, so unless it's saved, it won't auto-rejoin and has to be manually reconnected.

Edit:
Make sure you have explicitly defined join and leave commands:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def botjoin(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("You aren't in a voice channel, join one and try again")


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def botleave(ctx):
    if ctx.voice_client:
        await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
        # await ctx.send("I'm leaving the voice channel")
    else:
        await ctx.send("I'm not in a voice channel")
```

Comment: thanks.what do you suggest me to do then?

Comment: @amirdadfar9193 is the error occurring after you disconnect the bot from the voice channel, or the discord server itself? Or, is it when you restart the python script?

Comment: its after i disconnect the bot from voice channel i have a disconnect function for it or even when i use kick from voice channel on discord itself as im an admin in that server . @daniel-s
when i restart the python script it works fine but its not available for me to restart the script every time

Comment: @amirdadfar9193 have you defined explicit JOIN and LEAVE commands within the bot? See my edit above. My assumption is that it's erroring out because of something in your leave command if so -- what does the console output when you make it leave?